# Linux writing to /dev/hidraw2 from java

Tags: java, linux, io, outputstream

I want to write to `/dev/hidraw2` in my java program. (To switch the LEDs of my Buzz-controllers on/off)

On command line (in sudo mode)
`echo -e "\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00" > /dev/hidraw2`
(LED of controller 3 = on)
works fine.

I want to accomplish the same in java.

Here is what I tried:

```
  public static final //
  void setLEDs(//
      final boolean v1,//
      final boolean v2,//
      final boolean v3,//
      final boolean v4) throws IOException{
    OutputStream out =new BufferedOutputStream (new FileOutputStream("/dev/hidraw2", false));
    // writing to a file looks fine:
    // OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/home/test/temp-buzz-leds.t", false);  
    //         cat temp-buzz-leds.t | xxd  -g7 -c7
    //         00000000: 0000ffffffff00  .......

    // working command line example:   echo -e "\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00" > /dev/hidraw2
    byte[] data= new byte[]{(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,
        (byte)(v1?0xFF:0x00),
        (byte)(v2?0xFF:0x00),
        (byte)(v3?0xFF:0x00),
        (byte)(v4?0xFF:0x00),
        (byte)0x00};
    out.write(data);
    out.flush();      // line 150
    out.close();
  }//end-method
```

This is the Exception I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at BuzzeControler.setLEDs(BuzzeControler.java:150)
    at BuzzeControler.main(BuzzeControler.java:129)
```

---

By the way: Reading from `/dev/hidraw2` in java via *FileInputStream* works fine.

I hope someone with experience writing to linux devices can help.

Comment: What research did you do?

Comment: @Shubham Prashar: As mentioned in my question: 1. I successfully acheafed the desired behavior from commandline. 2. I wrote the bytes to a file instead of the device and analysed that they are correct. Than I googled for possible sources for "Broken pipe" related with FileOutputStream but found no reason why it occurres writing to the device but not when writing to a file.